# Deleting Alert sharepoint 2007 - Access denied

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In a live system, where we have never had trouble deleting alerts (its been up and running for about a year now), we have come accross this for one user on 2 particular alerts, the problem is we cannot delete either alert using any account (The users, my Admin accounts, the sharepoint installer account)- We get an access denied error. Now, the 2 alerts are set on the same document, which is held withing library X and to parent folders (X/FolderA/FolderB/Document)- After setting up the alert FolderA (And all its contents) were moved to a new library (Library z), and the alert stayed where it is, set up on library x - To my understanding sharepoint should've deleted it when it was moved?

We've tried the following;

Recreating FolderA/FolderB/Document structure in x
Cutting and pasting FolderA back into X (so it had the same Guids)

But we still could not delete the alert using any of the accounts :S Does anyone have any idea how we might be able to delete the aler?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with one of my main portal site. I escalate ticket with Microsoft. After doing so many trouble shootings. Finally we created new web application with same name, host address and attached the content db.

Problem resolved.